# JavaScript in MapReduce

Tags: javascript, hadoop

I am running a mapreduce job using Table MapReduce Util which takes the hbase table data(1 million rows) as input,In mapper I am evaluating a particular set of expressions for every row input from hbase table and it was getting completed less time as long as expressions to be evaluated for a particular row were around 10 to 20.

But as the number of expressions have increased to 100's(to be calculated for every row in hbase table) my mapreduce job is taking so much time as i am evaluating the expressions sequentially using JavaScript. I tried multi threading inside map function but no luck as it is also taking same time.

So is there a way to use the jsengine.eval() in a parallel way..?